# Adding a new user to confluence-users group

Tags: confluence

I am not able to add a new user to the "confluence-users" group. I am able to add a new user to the database, and when I am trying to add him to the group, it says

`"User [Anonymous] does not have the required privileges."`

I guess, it needs admin privileges to add a user to group and how can I specify it while adding a user to group. I am using confluence 3.5 api and pls let me know how to achieve this.

My code looks like below..

`UserAccessor userAccessor = (UserAccessor)ContainerManager.getInstance().getContainerContext().getComponent("userAccessor");
Group group = userAccessor.getGroup(UserAccessor.GROUP_CONFLUENCE_USERS);
DefaultUser defaultUser = new DefaultUser(username,fullname,email);
User newuser = userAccessor.createUser(defaultUser,Credential.unencrypted(password));
userAccessor.addMembership(group,newuser);`

Comment: Just to clarify, *how* are you creating the user and trying to add them to a group? Are you not just doing it through the Administration Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UserManager userManager = (UserManager) ContainerManager.getComponent("userManager");
userManager.createUser(newUser, Credential.NONE);
groupManager.addMembership(group, user);
```

You'll need to inject the GroupManager in your class.